# Connecting maven with putty

Tags: maven-2, scp, putty, maven-deploy-plugin

I'm having issues using putty with the mvn-deploy-plugin.

I execute: mvn deploy

This is what my settings.xml look like:

```
<server>
  <id>website</id>
  <username>user</username>
  <!--<privateKey>c:\putty\id_rsa</privateKey> -->
  <configuration>
    <sshExecutable>c:\putty\plink</sshExecutable>
    <scpExecutable>c:\putty\pscp</scpExecutable>
  </configuration>
</server>
```

It always spits back the same message, that doesn't trigger a lot of results on Google.  It calls on website, then fails on the scp command.

[ERROR] BUILD ERROR

[INFO] Error retrieving previous build number for artifact 'com.mycompany.myproject:project:war': repository metadata for: 'snapshot com.mycomany.myproject:project:2.3-SNAPSHOT' could not be retrieved from repository: snapshots.liege due to an error: While configuring wagon for 'website': Unable to apply wagon configuration.

```
Cannot find setter nor field in org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.ssh.jsch.ScpWagon for 'sshExecutable'
```

I have tried adding exe (which makes more sense to me) and it is not made any difference.

Answer (score 1):

What protocol are you using for the URL under the `<distributionManagement>` element? If you are using  `scp://`, you need to use `scpexe://` instead.